# Changing one 'char' at the String Vector's element in Java

Tags: java, string, vector

Today, I've come up with another problem: how can I change one char of the element at the Vector? I've used the replace method, but it doesn't work.... the Sample code is like below:

```
Vector<String> matrix = new Vector<String>();
word = "elephant"
matrix.add("abcde");
matrix.add("bcdef");
matrix.get(0).replace(matrix.get(0).charAt(1), word.charAt(1));
```

What I want to do here is change the 'b' at the first element of matrix into 'l', which is second char of the String word. I've researched a bit, and I've found out that in Java, String is immutable: which means I have to make a new String to save the changes. But, I'm stuck at this point. So, please help..!!!

**EDIT**
So, I've made a few changes in the code, and the code is now in this state:

```
Vector<String> matrix = new Vector<String>();
word = "elephant"
matrix.add("abcde");
matrix.add("bcdef");
String newString = matrix.get(0).replace(matrix.get(0).charAt(1), word.charAt(1));
matrix.get(0) = newString;
```

But this code invokes a error, 'The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable'. How can I fix this problem? Waiting for a kind answer....!!

Comment: Since String's are immutable, if you change a character, you have made a new String. Therefore the String still stored in the Vector hasn't changed. You need to get the String, change it, then put it back in the same place.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thank you for the comment! But, when I try to make a new string and put it in the matrix's element by 'matrix.get(0).chatAt(1) = newString(which is the new String);, I get the error 'The left-hand side of the assignment must be a variable'. How can I fix this problem? I'll wait for your comment...!!

Comment: You should put the new String into the Vector in the same place as the old String. So if it was in element 0, then you should do 'matrix.delete(0); matrix.add(0, newString);'

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks for the answer!!! I will try this right away!!!